# Programmatically showing the summary of a post

Tags: 6, nodes

What's the PHP code to call summary of a post (teaser) in a custom page?

I use Drupal 6 and I want to show a small part of a specific post in a custom page.

Comment: node_teaser() for Drupal 7, text_summary() for 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use teasers from node. In [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/6) you can use `$teaser` variable to print it.
In other templates, you need to use [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/6).

```
$node = node_load(211); // 211 is the Node ID
print $node->teaser;
```

Comment: Thanks, It works great. how can I find out other properties related to $node? like "title"?

Comment: Just print `$node` (`print_r($node)`). You will get other related data for that node including title.

Comment: Keep in mind that $teaser is not same as node_teaser() always because user can enter a different teaser instead of allowing Drupal to trim the content at a length.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the $teaser variable, you can also use the `node_teaser()` function ([http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_teaser/6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_teaser/6)). This allows you to create a custom teaser, in case $teaser is not present.

Answer (score 1):

The function that creates the teaser of a node is [node_teaser()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_teaser/6), which is called from [node_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_submit/6), the function called from the form submission handler for the node edit form, and from [node_preview()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_preview/6), the function used to create a preview of the node being saved.

It can happen a node doesn't have a teaser, for example when a module saves the node using [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/6). in such cases, you can use code similar to the following one.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
if (!isset($node->teaser)) {
  if (isset($node->body)) {
    $node->teaser = node_teaser($node->body, isset($node->format) ? $node->format : NULL);
  }
  else {
    $node->teaser = '';
    $node->format = 0;
  }
}
```

To notice that Drupal 7 doesn't have the `node_teaser()` function anymore, as the body of a node is a field.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno, It helped me out to fix my other problem.